# Size of parentheses in manuscript editor

Tags: math-mode

I recently received a manuscript in the proof stage from a journal. In the tex files I submitted, I included equations with the following form (using the `amsmath` package):

```
\begin{equation}
\bigl( 1-f(x) \bigr) \times \bigl( 1-g(z) \bigr)
\end{equation}
```

The equations I received from the journal rendered this as

```
\begin{equation}
\left( 1-f\left(x\right) \left) \times \left( 1-g\left(z\right) \right)
\end{equation}
```

which erases the relative size of the parentheses. The commands \bigl and \bigr do not work in the journal's equation editor. What alternatives can I use to size the parentheses in my equation?

Comment: normally, don't need the bigr/l. the journal's way is the correct one

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  That change is absolutely terrible!  You can try removing the `\left` and `\right` from the inner parens, but I'm not sure that will result in the outer ones really getting larger.  (And I sure hope the publisher wasn't the AMS.  They have been known to eliminate the size distinction between nested parens, but not by adding `\left` and `\right`.)

Comment: @anis -- Sorry.  Adding `\left` and `\right` is absolutely wrong here.  Its understandable if the parens should not be the default "normal" size, but if the default normal size is correct (which it is here), it's indefensible.

Comment: you are right @barbarabeeton, I didn't see correctly.

Comment: Gently remark that your equation is well typed in (I'd not use `\bigl/r`, but that's personal preference), while theirs is wrong. Apparently, their copy editors have strange ideas about `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It's very helpful to hear that the way I've typed the equations is acceptable! @barbarabeeton - it's not the AMS